# Sentence Classification on SNLI dataset

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am working on SNLI dataset [here](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/snli/) for sentence classification task. This dataset contains two sentences and need to tell whether 2nd sentence **entails**, **contradicts** or is **neutral** to the first sentence.

For classification purpose, I have implemented coccurrence matrix based SVM classification which gives around 70% accuracy.

Can someone please suggest any other NLP related classification strategy i.e using bigrams, or trigrams as I need to come up with some baseline.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using k-means clustering, which might sound a bit unconventional for this type of task, but use it as the following and you might get a solid baseline result.

1. Take the mean bag of words vector of each category in the training set, which in your case you'll end up with three vectors, and use that to train your k-means model with k=3.
2. Then, after making sure which "label" corresponds with each category (for example by predicting the category of each of your three mean vectors that we just calculated and seeing each of their labels), use the model to predict your test set.

(Optional) You can probably further improve the accuracy of the model by running PCA on the training data. This essentially de-correlates your features, which can lead to reducing noise.